# How do I use an integer from an other class in a method?

Tags: java, class

I have a lab for a high school comp sci class, I take integer input in the driver class, and pass that to a method in another class that uses the number to do a calculation and return the answer.

Whats an easy way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you're trying to produce with the output, you can simply use a "get" function inside your driver class after you've accepted your user input. The purpose of this function is to simply return the value of your variable.

Eg.

```
public int getVariable() {
     return x;
}
```

And then

```
secondClass.calculation(driver.getVariable());
```

Hope  this helps!